# java thread.sleep() take longer time after display sleep on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, thread-sleep

The target is to make current thread sleep some time, range from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds. The program runs normally when display is on. But after display go to sleep mode ( On MacOS, display could go to sleep after some system idle time), the Thread.sleep() would take much longer time to return. I.g.,

Thread.sleep(5000); // to sleep 5 sec, but actually it take 30+ seconds to return.

It seems like the cpu frequency has been downscale, but java jre code did not follow the changes. Tested on MacOS 10.12 + Java 8.

Question: How to make the thread sleep code to overcome this issue?

Sample Code: both cannot work on display sleep case.

```
public static void threadsleep(long  milliseconds) { 
     try { 
         Thread.sleep(milliseconds); 
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
         Logger.getLogger(FetchDailyOptions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
     } 
 } 



 public static void threadsleep(long  milliseconds) { 
     try { 
         if (milliseconds < 100) { 
             Thread.sleep(milliseconds); 
             return; 
         } 

         long targetMilli = System.currentTimeMillis() + milliseconds; 
         for (;;) { 
             Thread.sleep(100); // wait 100 milliseconds 
             if (System.currentTimeMillis() > targetMilli) { 
                 return; 
             } 
         } 
     } 
     catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
         Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
     }
```

### }

Comment: If this is really happening this way then it's likely happening at the OS level and not within Java's control.  Can you write a simple C program that does the same sleep and test if it happens when using native threads?